# Stop the movement of nodes in force layout d3.js

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I want to display the nodes and relationship between them from json file.
I am using force layout d3.js but there is alot of movement of nodes when the page is opened. 
I want to stop these movements and also want to stop the other node movements when one node is dragged.

Code : http://jsfiddle.net/bhgq017u/13/

```
var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    node,
    link;

svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attrs({'id':'arrowhead',
        'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX':13,
        'refY':0,
        'orient':'auto',
        'markerWidth':8,
        'markerHeight':8,
        'xoverflow':'visible'})
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
    .attr('fill', "gray");

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {return d.id;}).distance(500).strength(1))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json('https://api.myjson.com/bins/beqb0', function (error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;
    update(graph.links, graph.nodes);
})

function update(links, nodes) {
    link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')

    link.append("title")
        .text(function (d) {return d.type;});

    edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attrs({
            'class': 'edgepath',
            'fill-opacity': 0,
            'stroke-opacity': 0,
            'id': function (d, i) {return 'edgepath' + i}
        })
        .style("pointer-events", "none");

    edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attrs({
            'class': 'edgelabel',
            'id': function (d, i) {return 'edgelabel' + i},
            'font-size': 10,
            'fill': 'black'
        });

    edgelabels.append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) {return '#edgepath' + i})
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr("startOffset", "50%")
        .text(function (d) {return d.type});

    node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
              //  .on("end", dragended)
        );

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 8)
        .style("fill", function (d, i) {return colors(i);})

    node.append("text")
        .attr("dy", -10)
        .text(function (d) {return d.name});

    simulation
        .nodes(nodes)
         .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(links);
}

function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
        .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
        .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
        .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});

    node
        .attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";});

    edgepaths.attr('d', function (d) {
        return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
    });

    edgelabels.attr('transform', function (d) {
        if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
            var bbox = this.getBBox();

            rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
            ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
            return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
        }
        else {
            return 'rotate(0)';
        }
    });
}

function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}
```

Comment: I can't find `/Users/poosachd/Desktop/d3folder/abc1.json` on the internet, use `myjson.com`

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/beqb0

Comment: in the `dragend` you must set the `alphaTraget` to 0

Comment: or remove the forces at the end of the simulation or on dragstart

Answer (score 0):

In the dragend you must set the alphaTraget to 0.

Remove the forces on dragstart

```
function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  simulation.force("link", null).force("charge", null).force("center", null);
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
}
```

**Edit**

If you also want to restrict at startup use

```
function update(links, nodes) {
    // ...
    simulation
        .nodes(nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked)
        .stop();

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(links);

    d3.range(100).forEach( () => simulation.tick() );
    ticked();
    simulation.force("link", null).force("charge", null).force("center", null);
    simulation.start();
}
```

Comment: The movement of the nodes stop when the drag is started. But when the application is started the nodes are already moving. I want to stop that as well.